# Datatables open dropdown inside a cell

Tags: css, datatables

I am in trouble with my CSS and I don't find the problem!

Inside the last cell of my datatables I've a dropdown menu that appear clicking on it.

The problem is that the menu "stay" inside the cell and show me scroller!

[image]

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oxs8fp4e/1/

This is my code for table init, but the problem I think is inside CSS of the theme, not table init:

```
myTable = $('#tabellaArticoli').DataTable({
    responsive: {
            details: {
                type: 'column',
                target: 0
            }
        },
        paging: true,
        "pageLength": 100,
        "lengthMenu": [ [20, 50, 100, -1], [20, 50, 100, "Tutti"] ],
        "info": false,
        scrollCollapse: false,
        scrollX: false,
        scrollY: false,
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                orderable: false,
                className: 'control',
                searchable: false,
                targets:   0
            },
            { "orderable": false, "targets": 1 },
            { "width": "5%", "orderable": false, "targets": 'azioni' }
        ]
  });
```

Instead i'd like to show the dropdown like this example: https://keenthemes.com/metronic/preview/demo7/crud/datatables/basic/basic.html

[image]

Can someone help me with my css?

EDIT: I've already set scrollX as false: this is not the problem. I think the problem is only inside the CSS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Row containing a button dropdown causes vertical scrolling when scrollX is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56384285/row-containing-a-button-dropdown-causes-vertical-scrolling-when-scrollx-is-enabl)

Comment: Hi @Jan, I've seen you link but it is not my case: 1. I don't use scrollX true (I use it as FALSE)...also the example linked in you comment still doesn't solve the problem...scroller still appear

Answer (score 0):

It's nearly the same problem as linked in the 'possible duplicate'-comment. Your table and one or more wrapping elements got the `overlow: hidden;` style assigned.

In your case you could do the following to achieve that the whole popup-menu becomes visible.

1. remove/override the `overflow`-styles:

```css
.table-responsive,
.dataTables_scrollBody {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

2. Change the transform of the `dropdown-menu`-elements defined by the inline-styles:

```css
transform: translate3d(-120px, 20px, 0px);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Your edit is good if datatable is responsive = true. If you disable responsive, adding your code and opening the page in small screens, you can see some columns goes outside the screen also if X scroller is present! see fiddle in small screen: http://jsfiddle.net/umjdeLnq/1/